# check multiple checkboxes Ajax &jquery & Spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I try to check  multiple checkboxes not all using Ajax call.It works fine but when I uncheck them, just one unchecked and the others go to check again.

Ajax call for check and uncheck:

```
   $(function(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').bind("change",function(){ 

if($(":checkbox[path='description']:checked").length > 0 ){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.html',
        data: { "id": $(this).attr('cid')},
        success: function(data){
        }

    });
}

else{

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'uncheck.html',
        data: { "id": $(this).attr('cid')},
        success: function(data){
        }
    });


}

});

 });
```

html part, for loop for the checkpoints:

```
        <c:forEach var = "c" items = "${planid.checkpoints}" varStatus="status">

                         <c:if  test = "${c.st eq s.name and c.rw eq r.name}">

                         <p><input  cid="${c.id}" class= "case" path="description" type="checkbox" value="${c.description}"   />
                         <c:out  value = "${c.description}"></c:out>

                        <security:authorize access="hasRole('admin')">                              
                        <a href="/gefp/jsp/Edit.html?id=${c.id}">[Edit]</a>
                        </security:authorize>

                        </p>

                    </c:if>

                 </c:forEach>
```

In the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/jsp/check.html") 
      @ResponseBody
      public  ResponseEntity<String> check(@RequestParam Long id,     HttpSession session){

        String u=SecurityUtils.getUsername();
         User user=userDao.getUser(u).get(0);        
         user.getId();

         Checkpoint cp = userDao.getCheckpoint(id);         

         user.getCheckpoints().add(cp);
         userDao.saveUser(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>( HttpStatus.OK );

    }



    @RequestMapping("/jsp/uncheck.html") 
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void uncheck(@RequestParam Long id){   

         String u=SecurityUtils.getUsername();
         User user=userDao.getUser(u).get(0);        
         user.getId();

        Checkpoint cp = userDao.getCheckpoint(id);
        user.getCheckpoints().remove(cp);
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }
```

Comment: Your ajax request expects 1 id per request or all checked ids should be sent in a single request?

Comment: also what about the uncheck call when should it happen

Comment: @Arun P Johny. Edited it. Could you please check it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing

```
$(function(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){ 
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

if(checked){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.html',
        data: { "id": $(this).attr('cid')},
        success: function(data){
        }

    });
}

else{

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'uncheck.html',
        data: { "id": $(this).attr('cid')},
        success: function(data){
        }
    });


}

});

 });
```